# I have trouble making a canvas take up the full window using HTML5 and JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to code a basic game. However, I keep running into the issue that scroll bars appear, meaning that something is bigger than it should be. I looked into it a bit, and it seems it is the html tag which is too high for the window. I need to know how to fix this.

This is the code I'm using to make it take the whole window (these are the first 3 lines of code):

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your canvas to take up whole space, you could just add this to your canvas properties.

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
canvas.width = "100vw";
canvas.height = "100vh";
```

or

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
canvas.width = "100vw";
canvas.height = "100%";
```

> The vh stands for viewport height and
> vw for viewport width.

What it does is basically occupy the height and width of your viewport in the browser.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure the issue was the HTML tag but someone just told me how to fix the issue in a different way. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your html and body are not adding any margin or padding:

**css**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

2. Use css to set your mainCanvas element to viewport extents and suggested in Aditya's answer:

**css**

```
#mainCanvas {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just found out I can put `overflow: hidden;` in the CSS which fixes my problem.

Comment: Using that approach without understanding why you had the issue in the first place is likely to be storing up trouble.  At some stage later you might be drawing something on that "mainCanvas" and find part of it truncated from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: PS.  Use your browser developer tools options (Ctrl-Shift-I on Chrome), selected "Elements" and then click the top right element selector.  You can then hover over the elements on the page to find the offending element and style / css.